# how to escape and print # in echo statment gitlab CI yaml file

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Can someone confirm me - how to escape the # in gitlab script section?  cause when I added :

```
script:
  - echo "# asdsad" >> README.md
```

, its considering everything after # as commented out section. What I expect it to do ideally is add # asdsad in markdown format that we do normally whenever updating README.md file.

I tried to escape using #/ as well as /# but nothing helped

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thats because of the yaml syntax interpreter, use either

```
  - |
    echo "# asdsad" >> README.md
```

Or

```
  - >
    echo "# asdsad" >> README.md
```

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html